# How to use laravel package repository with fractal parameter includes?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-request

I am using [repository](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/prettus/l5-repository#create-a-presenter) package to make API with laravel.I use transformers to transform data.It works well.
I am wondering how can I use includes with transformers.
As a example I have user class.I want to include UserBook model in User transformers.

I added following code to UserTransformer

```
protected $defaultIncludes = [
    'user_books',
];

 public function includeUserBooks(User $user){
        $project_books = $user->userBooks;

        return $project_books;
    }
```

But it is not return include.How can I call it through controller ?

Thank you.

Comment: You still need help with this problem?

Comment: No, I managed to do it the other way.